# Laravel authentication not working

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am working on trying to authenticate users with the Laravel framework. At this point I've copied line for line from several tutorials, and nothing has worked.

Below I have the controller code that is trying to do the authentication. I know that the input is correct to what's stored in the database (I've done a var dump of the input), yet it still won't authenticate. Here's the code.

```
public function handleLogin() {
        $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            echo "YES";
        }
        echo "FAILURE";
    }
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The password field on the database needs to be 60 characters in order for it to work.